# (fluent) nhibernate - Select Object based on subclass of referenced base class in query

Tags: nhibernate, reference, fluent-nhibernate, subclass, fluent

I have 4 classes
Person (has a reference to a type Animal (will contain a class that inherits Animal))
Animal (abstract base)
Dog (inherit Animal)
Cat (inherit Animal)

Just to be clear i am using Table-per-class mapping so i have an Animal, Dog and Cat DB tables.

What i want to do is select every person that has a Dog and if possible be able to filter on fields in the dog class.  If at all possible i would prefer to to do all this via type safe code and not direct SQL or strings if possible to stop code breaking over time.

Is this possible with  (fluent 1.2) nhibernate (3.1)?  Can someone start pointing me in the right direction?  My query is a little more complicated than explained but that is the core of it.

Also a little off topic but is there anywhere that has a description of all the methods under  mappingSession.QueryOver()?  There are so many things there and some are obvious but others like Fetch etc are not clear exactly what they all do and could be why i am finding this so hard.

--- EDIT Classes for reference ---

```
 public class Person
{
    Animal pet;
    public string Name;
}

public abstract class Animal
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public string Color;
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public string someOtherVal;
}
```

Using just a session object i want to get all distinct people Names where they have a pet of type Dog and the Dog is brown.

That is the final query i want to end up with but i was try to start with just getting people that have a dog as i thought that would be easy but it seems that it is not the case.

My original Querys i tried were

```
Dog dog = null;
            var test2 = session.QueryOver<Person>()
                .Inner.JoinAlias(x=>x.Pet, ()=> dog)
                .Where(()=>dog != null)
                .List();
```

i also had projections to reduce it distinct name but i still could not get it to restrict to just people with Dogs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can accomplish this:

http://jameskovacs.com/2011/02/16/getload-polymorphism-in-nhibernate-3/

```
var animal = session.CreateCriteria<Animal>()
                    .Add(Restrictions.IdEq(dogId))
                    .UniqueResult<Animal>();
```

You can also try something like this, i'm not 100% sure it will work, but you can give it a try:

```
var animal = session.CreateCriteria<Animal>()
                     .Add(Restrictions.On<Dog>(m=>m.Id == 1))
                     .UniqueResult<Animal>();
```

Does this help?

Comment: thanks i will do some more reading and testing tomorrow but i think that will hopefully get me close if no work perfectly. Only issue is all i have is the session and not a person to pass in but maybe the doco will make that clear to me

Comment: Ok, let me know if you have any problems!

Comment: I am still having issues. Where are you getting your Person object from and should it be person or animal? Also i get compile errors with the m=>m.Id == person.Id part as it is not a projection or something.

Comment: I updated my original post to have the classes and my original query before you posted your answer.  I did not post my copy of your answer as it would not compile so i think i was going down the wrong track.

Comment: I will take a look at your code and update my answer, hold tight!

Comment: Any luck? At the minute it seems like i may need to change my design or just use SQL

Comment: still not really what i am looking for.  I al trying to find all people that have Dogs as a start and the filter based on fields on the dog later on.  Sure that would return a list of animals that i could then search people that have one of those animals but the i could have just queried Dogs directly. Or is there some way to add that to the join from Person to Animal in the query that i am missing?

Comment: I still think that the link i provided will solve your problem. I will create a test project and try this out, i'll post my findings ok?

Comment: any luck with the test project. I have changed my design to work around this issue for now but would still love to know the solution if there is one.